# JavaFX (8) Modena: Default font size for labels

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

What is the default font size for labels in JavaFX' Modena design?

I know there is this CSS in the JAR but is there an easy way to determine such values?

Comment: css is the best way

Comment: Since the value may change, us a layout that accommodates whatever size is present.

Comment: Where do I find it in the CSS? Is there even a documentation for the CSS file?

Comment: @tashgod That doesn't help me, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Reading CSS is the best option to know defaults for one particular release. To get this CSS you can unzip the jar file:

JDK7,8:

```
"$JAVA_HOME/bin/jar" xvf "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar"  com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css
```

JDK9

```
"$JAVA_HOME/bin/jmod" extract "$JAVA_HOME/jmods/javafx.controls.jmod"
cat classes/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css
```

You can find documentation for JavaFX CSS here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Answer (score 0):

try override the label css, this will multiply all labels size by 1.1

```
.label {
  -fx-font-size:1.1em
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in modena.css: https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470 (lines 48-55).

From line 54-55:

> The default sizes are based on Windows default of 12px, as a quick
> reference here are common px sizes in em units on windows.